# Reading JSON from a URL in Java avoiding 401 error

Tags: java, json, http-status-code-401

I have been trying to read the json data from a url but I am keep getting error 401. Is there any way to add authentication method with base 64 encoder to get the json data?
Please let me know. Thanks

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

public class jsonFetcher {

public static void loadDocument() throws Exception {
    URL url = new URL("http://cmvd9k0n.dev.cm.par.emea.cib:8080/api/v1/topology/summary");
    try {
        File destination = new File("dest.json");
        // Copy bytes from the URL to the destination file.
        FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, destination);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Please check [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly. What have you tried doing, how is your current code, etc

Comment: For sure there is a way to add authentication data. It depends on what the server expects, and concise instructions would imply what HTTP library you are using.

Comment: @re_arg I have edited can you give an answer now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To perform this request with the authentication headers you will need to use a `HTTP Client`. Depending on your needs and Java version that can be the [Apache Http Client](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/index.html), the [Java 11 native Http Client](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html), [Spring Rest Template](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html), or many others.

Using Apache HTTP Client:

```java
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.RequestBuilder;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;

HttpClient client = HttpClients.custom().build();
HttpUriRequest request = RequestBuilder.get()
 .setUri("http://cmvd9k0n.dev.cm.par.emea.cib:8080/api/v1/topology/summary")
 .setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "yourBase64EncodedCreds")
 .build();
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

the json data you want will be within the `HttpResponse` object.